# How to convert a LONG for x,y of cursor to logical units

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I made some screen capturing software using `winapi` and to add the functionality for it to take a screenshot of where the cursor is. I made a `POINT` struct to contain the x and y values I got from the `GetCursorPos` function and I tried to place the members `x` and `y` into the `nXDest` and `nYDest` parameters of `BitBlt`.

The only problem is that because the members of `POINT` are `LONG`'s I get really long random numbers such as 1188087969 where `BitBlt` is expecting logical units and/or `int`'s. Is there any mathematical calculation I could do to convert this to a usable value for `BitBlt`? Or is there another method of solving this problem?

```
HBITMAP GetScreenShot(HBITMAP hBitmap)
{
    HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(NULL);
    hMemoryDC     = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

    int width  = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES)/2; 
    int height = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES)/2; 
    LPPOINT mp;
    GetCursorPos(mp);
    cout << "X: " << mp->x << "\nY:" << mp->y << endl;

    hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, width, height);

    HGDIOBJ hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    return hBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Please show some example code; numbers like that make it sound like the `POINT` structure may just be uninitialized.

Comment: Petzold discussed the Windows GDI measuring unit conversions extensively in his "Programming Windows" book (5th edition or earlier).

Comment: Pointer `mp` is used uninitialized. So you have **Undefined Behavior**. Declare a `POINT` (not a pointer), and pass its address to `GetCursorPos`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf sorry, I wrote my answer before I saw your comment which says exactly the same thing 2 minutes earlier.

Comment: @MarkRansom: He he :) It was much worse on Usenet (decentralized best effort article propagation). Could be delay of up to days from you posted someting till it showed up.

Comment: Showing your age, fellas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
LPPOINT mp;
GetCursorPos(mp);
cout << "X: " << mp->x << "\nY:" << mp->y << endl;
```

Is using an uninitialized pointer, which is undefined behavior.  You need to do this instead:

```
POINT mp;
GetCursorPos(&mp);
cout << "X: " << mp.x << "\nY:" << mp.y << endl;
```

Comment: Genius! Very much appreciated, can't believe I didn't think about that.